# Xamarin Forms - Multiple DataTemplate ListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

From my previous experience and some research on the web, I don't know if it's possible to have the following behavior:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
  <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="#2F767B">
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ScreenLayoutAdapter" BackgroundColor="#235A5E"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
      <AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle" Android="0, 0, 1, 1" iOS="1, 1, 1, 0.975" WinPhone="0, 1, 1, 1"/>
      </AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>

      <ListView x:Name="ListViewCourses" BackgroundColor="Transparent" RowHeight="90"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,0.9,0.9"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <AbsoluteLayout Margin="2">

              <!-- Your design for the cell template -->

              </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In the c# side, I then have a `ObservableCollection<Item>` that I bind with the `ListViewCourses`.

But now my question is:

**When I touch an item, how can I change of DataTemplate cell?**

I mean, it's a list of items but when I touch one, I want that the cell grows up and displays more information, about the item selected.

If I have to bring more information to make you understand, tell me

Thank in advance ! :)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do, instead of changing the `DataTemplate` of a single item, is have all of the controls containing the extra information that you want to show, be set to `IsVisible = false` and then when it is clicked, set `IsVisible = true` on all the controls and also call `ListView.ForceLayout()` to force the `ViewCell` to get redrawn.

Finally, make sure `ListView.HasUnevenRows = true` or else the `ViewCell` will not change size.

Alternatively, you may be able to add the controls containing extra information to the `ViewCell` when it is selected, it may or may not be slower/faster depending on the number of items in the `ListView`, the amount of extra controls you are adding, and whether you need to query the DB or a service for that extra information.

Let me know if you have any questions/issues.

Edit: Actually, you will want to call `ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize()`, info [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Runtime_Resizing_of_Rows), in order to change the size of the `ViewCell` once selected. You also may need to store that `ViewCell` instance in a class level variable so that you can shrink it back down when the user clicks a different `ViewCell` in the list.

Edit #2: One last thing I have run into, is that on iOS, if you have enabled `ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement` on your `ListView`, you will most likely not see any change in the `ViewCell` after making controls visible and calling `ForceUpdateSize()`. This might have something to do with the last paragraph [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/#RecycleElement), but I am not sure how to properly fix/get around it at this time.

Edit #3: For example you might do something like this:

```
<ViewCell>

     <!-- Use ListView.ItemTapped instead of the TapGestureRecognizer below -->
    <!-- <ViewCell.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnViewCellTapped"/>
    </ViewCell.GestureRecognizers> -->
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Main info displayed by default -->
        <StackLayout StyleId="DefaultStackLayout">
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemDates}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemCredits}"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Extra info displayed upon selection -->
        <StackLayout StyleId="ExtraStackLayout"
                     IsVisible="False">
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemBuilding}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemTeacher}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemHours}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Then when the user selects the cell, you would need to do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void OnViewCellTapped(object sender, EventArgs args) {}
    tapCount++;
    ViewCell viewCellSender = (ViewCell)sender;

    StackLayout rootStack = (StackLayout)viewCellSender.View;

    StackLayout extraInfoStack = rootStack.Children.Where(stack => stack.StyleId == "ExtraStackLayout");
    extraInfoStack.IsVisible = true;

    viewCellSender.ForceUpdateSize();
}
```

I have not tested any of this or even attempted it before, so if the above does not work, I am confident that inserting the `extraInfoStack` element content once the `ViewCell` is clicked, will work. But give the above a try first. Obviously you will need to change the layouts if you want to use `AbsoluteLayout` and you will also need to change the `OnViewCellTapped()` casting code.

Edit #4: I usually try to steer clear of constant numbers for height and width values if possible but sometimes it is unavoidable. So for this all to work you are going to have to set `ListView.HasUnevenRows = true` and that means you will need to get rid of your `ListView.RowHeight` value completely since the rows need to be allowed to have variable height.

If at all possible, I would try to not set a constants height value, but if you absolutely cannot live without setting the height to a constants value, then you can probably give your `ViewCell`'s inner `AbsoluteLayout` a `HeightRequest` of 120, but then you would need to change that value when the item is selected, after making your extra controls visible and before calling `ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize()`. Setting `IsVisible` to `false` is supposed to make it so that the control does not take up any space, so those extra controls should not mess with the sizing while they are hidden but I have never tried it myself.

If you run into issues, please let me know.

Comment: Thank for your answer :) So you mean I would have to create, into my `datatemplate xaml`, **two main layout** into the `ViewCell` and then, make only one at the time `Visible`?

Comment: Ok honestly, this answer is so perfect, Thank !! I imagined it really harder... `<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnViewCellTapped"/>` as listener... I wanted to add a listener for each item..  Such an idiot when I see your code ;) As you told, yeah I'll need to update the `layout`, but a question comes in my mind at the moment, how can you deal with the resize of a `cell` of the `ListView`? I mean mine is defined by `Rows.Height="120"`

Comment: @Emixam23 Glad it was helpful and I did not see that before. I am assuming you are referring to the `ListView.RowHeight` value you have set? If so, see edit #4 (did not have enough room in the comments). And now that you mention it, you should use `ListView.ItemTapped` instead of that `TapGestureRecognizer`, they will act more or less the same. Was not thinking correctly. I edited my answer.

Comment: **First**, thank as always x) **Second**, I have to deal with this fixed size for the design... However, I'm only dealing with proportional values ! **Third**, I cannot get ride of the C# part, `Content` doesn't Exist, `Children` too :/ If I understand, `View` could replace `Content`, what do you think? **#EDIT** ARRRGG it doesn't works and I can't figure this out ><

Comment: Hi, did you see my comment? :) @hvaughan3

Comment: @Emixam23 2) You should be able to add the Height value to the `AbdoluteLayout.HeightRequest` like I said. 3) Which c# part are you talking about? Maybe edit your question and include what you have so far so I can understand what the issue is.

Comment: I would say your C# part doesn't work :/ I have issues about `(StackLayout)viewCellSender.Content;` where `Content` do not exist. `rootStack.Children.Where(stack => stack.StyleId == "ExtraStackLayout");` doesn't wor too, I can't compile them both..

Comment: @Emixam23 In terms of the first issue, change `(StackLayout)viewCellSender.Content;` to `(StackLayout)viewCellSender.View;`. For the other issue, `.Where()` needs `System.Linq;` so make sure to add `using System.Linq;` to your code-behind. Will update my answer to fix those things.